# How can I chain functions and choose which one to execute in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I want to be able to chain functions as seen below and choose between them. In this contrived example, I hardcoded "function_b", but in the ideal world, I'd like it to be random or even controlled by a server. I know that I can create the same effect in different ways, but I like the way this code reads, so I want to do it like this.

```
ExecutionManager("function_b").add("function_a") {
    //some code
}.add("function_b") {
    //more code
}.add("function_c") {
    //other code
}
```

Comment: You could store the functions in a dictionary. Instead of `"function_b"` you then access the dictionary `func_dct["function_b"]`.

Comment: Again, I'm not trying to ask for alternative ways to perform this task, I'm asking how I can perform the task in this way

Comment: Have you tried implementing this yourself? If so, show the code, if not, do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your snipped of code does not make much sense to me. E.g. what should mean this part?

```
ExecutionManager("function_b")
```

You are just passing a string to the initializer of `ExecutionManager`. What should be the meaning of that?

### Let's try

However if you want to be able to add a list of functions with this type

```
() -> ()
```

and then execute them (all of them or just some of them) you could define your `ExecutionManager` like this

```
class ExecutionManager {

    typealias FunctionType = () -> ()

    private var functions = [(String, FunctionType)]()

    func add(funcName: String, function: FunctionType) -> ExecutionManager {
        functions.append(funcName, function)
        return self
    }

    func runAll() {
        functions.forEach { $0.1() }
    }
}
```

### Now you can

```
ExecutionManager().add("sayHello") { 
    print("hello")
}.add("sum 1 + 1") {
    let sum = 1 + 1
    print(sum)
}.add("say goodbye") { 
    print("goodbye")
}.runAll()
```

The result is

```
hello
2
goodbye
```

### Random

To run a only a function based on some logic look at this code. here I am generating a random index and the executing only one function

**Extension**

```
extension ExecutionManager {
    func runRand() {
        guard functions.isEmpty == false else { return }
        let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(functions.count)))
        functions[rand].1()
    }
}
```

**Example**

```
ExecutionManager().add("sayHello") {
    print("hello")
}.add("sum 1 + 1") {
    let sum = 1 + 1
    print(sum)
}.add("say goodbye") {
    print("goodbye")
}.runRand()
```

**Output**

```
2
```

### Update

With this version we remove the invocation of runRand at the end

*@HyperZ Thanks for the hint.*

```
import Foundation

class ExecutionManager {

    typealias FunctionType = () -> ()

    private var functions = [(String, FunctionType)]()

    func add(funcName: String, last:Bool=false, function: FunctionType) -> ExecutionManager {
        functions.append(funcName, function)
        if last {
            runRand()
        }
        return self
    }

    func runRand() {
        guard functions.isEmpty == false else { return }
        let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(functions.count)))
        functions[rand].1()
    }
}
```

**Code**

```
ExecutionManager().add("sayHello") {
    print("hello")
}.add("sum 1 + 1") {
    let sum = 1 + 1
    print(sum)
}.add("say goodbye", last:true) {
    print("goodbye")
}
```

**Output**

```
hello
```

Comment: The purpose would be to just run one of them. I guess I am trying to avoid adding the function at the end, in this case the `runAll`

Comment: @mergesort: One of them? You mean a random one?

Comment: Based on some arbitrary logic.

Comment: @mergesort: ok please take a look at the new section into my answer

Comment: Yeah, that's almost there. Do you think it would be possible to avoid running the `runRand` function? I think in order for that to happen, the added functions would need to be some sort of parameter to the initializer, right? Or is there any other way?

Comment: @mergesort: I added a new section. Now you can omit the `runRand()` at the end. But you need to pass a specific param `last` to the last `add` as suggested by _HyperZ_

Comment: Great, thanks! I guess you can also create an `addLast` function that will add the last one and run something as well to keep the signatures consistent.

Comment: I'm also experimenting with variadic parameters as well.

Comment: @mergesort: yes `addLast` is definitely another solution