# How can I chain functions when i call it in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, chain

I am beginner in swift and I'm doing exercises to learn.

I have to filter any numbers that are even, sort the array, map them to string and print the result one item per line.

The problem is, when I call the function, I´m not able to chain the closures, and it only prints the third function.

```
import Foundation

let luckyNumbers = [7, 4, 38, 21, 16, 15, 12, 33, 31, 49]

func doImportantWorkChain (first: ([Int]) -> [Int], second: ([Int]) -> [Int], third: ([Int]) -> [String]) {
    first(luckyNumbers)
    second(luckyNumbers)
    third(luckyNumbers)

    third(luckyNumbers).forEach {
        print($0)
    }
}

doImportantWorkChain { number in
    return number.filter {
        return $0.isMultiple(of: 2)
    }
} second: { number in
    return number.sorted {
        return $0 < $1
    }
} third: { number in
    return number.map {
       ("\($0) is the lucky number")
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
7 is the lucky number
4 is the lucky number
38 is the lucky number
21 is the lucky number
16 is the lucky number
15 is the lucky number
12 is the lucky number
33 is the lucky number
31 is the lucky number
49 is the lucky number
```

**Output I have to get**

```
4 is the lucky number
12 is the lucky number
16 is the lucky number
38 is the lucky number
```

I know that I have to use: luckyNumbers.first { }.second { }

When I try to write like this Xcode give me error: value of type '(([Int]) -> [Int], ([Int]) -> [Int], ([Int]) -> [String]) -> ()' has no member 'first'

So I erase first and give me this errors:

Expected member name following '.'

Top-level statement cannot begin with a closure expression

Value of type '(_) -> _' has no member 'second'

```
doImportantWorkChain.first{ number in
    return number.filter {
        return $0.isMultiple(of: 2)
    }
}.second{ number in
    return number.sorted {
        return $0 < $1
    }
}.third{ number in
    return number.map {
       ("\($0) is the lucky number")
    }
}
```

Also I try to chain it when when I call them inside the function but doesn't work either.

Comment: Why not just chain calls to filter, sorted, and map?

Comment: In the exercise he ask that it have to be done that way. But I do not know if the way I have written the code that is possible.

Answer (score 2):

As the first answer suggested, the issue is that the result of a closure should be used in the next closure.

**The fastest way to get the output you are looking for**

```
func doImportantWorkChain(first: ([Int]) -> [Int],
                          second: ([Int]) -> [Int],
                          third: ([Int]) -> [String]) {

    third(second(first(luckyNumbers))).forEach {
        print($0)
    }
}
```

However, this is not really `chaining` functions together and it is doing what the first answer with and just reduces your lines of code but there is no real upgrade in this.

**The right way (IMO) to get the output you are looking for**

Chaining would be something that I believe one of the commenters suggested is using the filter, sort and map functions directly on `luckyNumbers` to get your desired output:

```
luckyNumbers
    .filter { $0.isMultiple(of: 2) }
    .sorted() { return $0 < $1 }
    .map { ("\($0) is the lucky number") }
    .forEach { print($0) }
```

**A way that is chaining, will give you the desired output but I don't know why you would ever use this**

If you think about what you need to do, to achieve some sort of chaining, you need to create your own `higher order` functions like `filter, map etc` with the same signatures as your closures and then executing the closures.

I did this by creating an `extension` for `Int` arrays

```
extension Array where Element == Int
{
    func apply(_ operation: ([Int]) -> [Int]) -> [Int]
    {
        return operation(self)
    }
    
    func apply(_ operation: ([Int]) -> [String]) -> [String]
    {
        return operation(self)
    }
}
```

Then you can achieve chaining and get your desired result

```
func doImportantWorkChain(first: ([Int]) -> [Int],
                          second: ([Int]) -> [Int],
                          third: ([Int]) -> [String]) {
    
    luckyNumbers
        .apply(first)
        .apply(second)
        .apply(third)
        .forEach { print($0) }
}
```

Again, this might be a nice exercise to work your brain and explore the language and its capabilities but I don't think you will ever really use this.

All three of the above ways will give you this output:

```
4 is the lucky number
12 is the lucky number
16 is the lucky number
38 is the lucky number
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking would be the way (I would call this `apply`).

Comment: @matt - just to clarify, you recommend changing `compute` to `apply` ?

Comment: Yes, that's the usual name for this kind of thing. But it's no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using results from previous functions to next.

If you do so then you will end up with error on this `third(luckyNumbers).forEach` line as function expected [Int] and you will be going to pass [String] as output from this `third(luckyNumbers)` call.

To work this code, you can have following modifications and run

```
 let luckyNumbers = [7, 4, 38, 21, 16, 15, 12, 33, 31, 49]

 func doImportantWorkChain (first: ([Int]) -> [Int], second: ([Int]) -> 
    [Int], third: ([Int]) -> [String]) {
    let first_result = first(luckyNumbers)
    let second_result = second(first_result)
    let third_result = third(second_result)

    for result in third_result {
      print(result)
    }
 }

doImportantWorkChain { number in
  return number.filter {
      return $0.isMultiple(of: 2)
  }
} second: { number in
  return number.sorted {
      return $0 < $1
  }
} third: { number in
  return number.map {
     ("\($0) is the lucky number")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! That will print the result I should have.

Would there be the possibility to chain it with "luckyNumbers.first { }.second { }"?

Because in the exercise he ask that it have to be done that way. Here he can chain it and i don´t undertand why  I can´t do it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282981/how-can-i-chain-functions-and-choose-which-one-to-execute-in-swift

Comment: But I still don't understand why you don't just _chain_ them if you want to chain them: `luckyNumbers.filter{$0 % 2 == 0}.sorted(by: <).map {print("the lucky number is", $0)}`. If you have a different assignment, why do you not tell us what that assignment _is?_

Comment: @Sara One important difference the linked question and your is that in the other question a class is used that the functions belong to but you have a standalone function without any class (or struct).

Comment: @matt For what I understand about the exercise I have to use functions and closures because is the challenge of that chapter.
This is the exercise but i think that you are right.
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/beginners/checkpoint-5

Okey Joakim I take into account and I get it now! :)
Thanks for the replies to all of you!